# AQGridView: no padding on outside, only inside

Tags: aqgridview

I have a 768px-wide grid view, with cells that are 240 wide. This means that I get 3 columns, with 8 pixels of padding on the left and right of each. This is similar to this situation: [AQGridView: How to adjust UIGridViewCell margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452887/aqgridview-how-to-adjust-uigridviewcell-margin).

Instead of evening out the padding, I want the padding to be only in the "middle", not on the outside of the outer columns.

So:
[ [cell] [24 pixels of padding] [cell] [24 pixels of padding] [cell] ]

Is this possible?